# How to animate overlay drawing in MKMapView

Tags: ios, animation, dictionary

I'm drawing `MKCircleView` overlay on `MKMapView`. it works fine, except that I need to animate drawing of this overlay.

I know that I need to use:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

,but I don't know where to put this animation code.

Thanks.

Comment: you put this code where you want to animate...simple! If you want to know how to use it, you just have to put the **code of change** you want to animate between `begin` and `commit`. You can find plenty of examples on SOF itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you're looking for.. but for example:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fade" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6f];
theView.alpha = 0.0f;
theView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01,0.01);
theView.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: There should be another theView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);   The code was used to take a view scale it to from tiny to full size and fade in from no opacity to full opacity.  The example above was just used for to display structure

Comment: I need to animate moving overlay from one location to another location on MKMap. Actually, the issue i'm facing is how to "move" ovarlay on map. currenlty, i'm just remove overlay from old location and add it again in new location, the issue with this, you could not animate this moveoment.

Comment: I have the same question. I want to animate movement of overlay. how can i acheive ?